# why links have different colors?

Tags: html

i am surprised why  these links have different color?here is code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ka-ge" lang="ka-ge" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<style>

#links { 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    width: 4800px; 
    font-size:70px;
    clear: both; 
    display: block;

}
#test a {
    float: right;
}
</style>
<body bgcolor="green" >
<a href="indexE.html"><img src ='english.gif' style="float:right"  width="88" height="88"> </a>
<a href="indexR.html"><img src ='russian.gif' alt="Russian flag" style="float:right"  width="88" height="88"/></a>
<a href="index.html"> <img src="georgian.jpg"  style="float:right" width="88" height="88"/></a>
<div id="links">
<a href=" index.html " >მთავარი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" ბაკურიანი.html ">ბაკურიანი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" გუდაური.html ">გუდაური </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" ზღვა.html ">ზღვა </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" კახეთი.html ">კახეთი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" სვანეთი.html ">სვანეთი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" ვარძია.html ">ვარძია </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" ქართლი.html ">ქართლი </a>
&nbsp;
<a href=" ძველი_თბილისი.html ">ძველი_თბილისი </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

when i run this in google chrome,everything has same color,except   ზღვა(sea),კახეთი(kakheti),ვარძია(vardzia),ქართლი(qartli) all this name  are in blue color,while others in other color,could you help me why  is so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the default styles for `:visited` or `:active`.

> The :visited selector is used to select visited links.
>
> The :active selector is used to select and style the active link.
>
> A link becomes active when you click on it.

**EDIT:** To make them all the same style you can do this:

```
a, a:active, a:visited {
    color: red;
}
```

That would style normal links, active links and visited links. You can also do rollovers using a:hover.

Comment: and how could i change my code,so that all links should be same colored?

Comment: this declaration should be alone,or in #links  style

Comment: a will select any <a> tag. If you put it as is in your CSS it will set them all to red.